# Evaluate Your Site -- A Check for Quality

Tags: discussion, quality-evaluation

One of the most important aspects of being a Stack Exchange site is quality. Yes, there are lots of metrics that one can use to "measure" a site, but we don't really care about those as much as we care about a site providing expert answers to good questions. To that end, we're introducing a self-evaluation to our sites!

This process is currently still in the midst of being put together, but you all are going to be a lucky early-adopter! Here's a rough guide:

- Below, you'll find ten questions randomly selected from your site.
- For each question, search the internet for the question as if you were the asker!
- If our answer is good (complete, well-written, answers the question, found in search results, etc) then **vote it up**!
- If our answer is bad (incomplete, poorly-written, off-topic, unfindable, etc) then **vote it down**!

Comment with anything you feel is worth noting, or to explain your voting choice. We have a rough guide to better/par/worse [right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQxi7.png). If your result is par, make a choice to vote up or down based on your instincts!

Ultimately, remember that our goal is to make the internet a better place. If you find yourself torn between the options, or if you can't decide, ask yourself: does this question and/or answer make the internet better? That should help you decide.

**This eval will close on March 21st! Get your answers in by then!**

Comment: An example from another site: [Judaism self-evaluation](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/836/site-self-evaluation-how-are-you-doing).

Comment: Example of `better`: [When using the blend tool in Illustrator, I get large white patches](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4006/when-using-the-blend-tool-in-illustrator-i-get-large-white-patches).

Comment: Example of `worse`: [Having trouble with a simple selection of a layer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4014/having-trouble-with-a-simple-selection-of-a-layer).

Comment: By "our answer" do you mean the highest voted or the accepted answers?

Comment: Thank you for your help, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

[Large-format printing suggestions](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5715/large-format-printing-suggestions)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Answer (score 1):

[Finding the right graphic designer for a project with no budget](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5677/finding-the-right-graphic-designer-for-a-project-with-no-budget)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Answer (score 1):

[Illustrator: Disabling random layer colors?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5734/illustrator-disabling-random-layer-colors)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Answer (score 1):

[How to create decorative borders for ebook / website use with fantasy theme?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/decorative-borders-for-ebook-website-use-with-fantasy-theme)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Answer (score 1):

[Reverse-engineer alpha channel](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5692/reverse-engineer-alpha-channel)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Answer (score 1):

[Separating a stock photograph from background](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5721/separating-a-stock-photograph-from-background)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Comment: "stock" is a huge keyword in this question. If it's included, it's the first result, else we don't even place.

Answer (score -1):

[Courier New-like font with Unicode support?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5697/courier-new-like-font-with-unicode-support)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Answer (score -1):

[Looking for suggestions for making type more readable with a drop shadow](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5823/looking-for-suggestions-for-making-type-more-readable-with-a-drop-shadow)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Answer (score -1):

[Is Gimpshop equally good as Gimp?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5669/is-gimpshop-equally-good-as-gimp)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Answer (score -1):

[I am not a graphic designer, what do I need to know so I don't come off as a complete luddite?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5709/i-am-not-a-graphic-designer-what-do-i-need-to-know-so-i-dont-come-off-as-a-com)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?